# Is it possible to get MariaDB4J to work on an M1 Mac?

Tags: java, mariadb, apple-m1, mariadb4j

I'm trying to get MariaDB4J working on my new M1 MacBook Pro, and I'm not doing so great.

I am running the Arm versions of both libssl@1.1 and mariadb 10.6.4, both installed with Homebrew.

First I had issues with libssl not finding libssl, it had to have 1.0, so i installed symlinks from the 1.0 path the library expects to the homebrew 1.1 destination. According to various issue threads on the mariadb GitHub page this should work.

So, it indeed resulted in that libssl was found, but now I get another issue in the logs:

"Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))"

So, I guess that something/mariadb4j expects the x86 version of libssl but I have arm? I'm not sure how to sort this out, so hoping that someone got this to work on M1. Pointers appreciated.

Comment: I copied libcrypto and libssl 1.0.0.dylib from my old x64 mac and moved them to the /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/ folder. That worked, however now I get another error: ```'/private/var/folders/tp/0_v20fj94sq38nsl2ynbjx6c0000gn/T/MariaDB4j/base/libproviders.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libproviders.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libproviders.dylib' (no such file)```

Comment: I was able to run all my tests using `testcontainers` with the latest MariaDB container available at Docker Hub (10.7.1) which is supported by ARM processors. I followed this guide: https://nirajsonawane.github.io/2019/12/25/Testcontainers-With-Spring-Boot-For-Integration-Testing/

Comment: Hey there good to hear you got it working. I did too, by instead pointing to a local mariadb install for my tests and skipping mariadb4j.  Will look into testcontainers, so that I won't have to rely on a mariadb install being present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of MariaDB4j, and can confirm that currently this is not possible / won't "just work". The reason is that what MariaDB4j does is simply package platform specific MariaDB binaries into JARs, and then natively `exec`utes the `mysqld`. And nobody has contributed the MariaDB binaries for M1 to MariaDB4j... but contributions to the project are very welcome! ;-) https://github.com/vorburger/MariaDB4j/issues/497 tracks this FR.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for responding. Too bad, i really like mariadb4j, but i can of course see why it doesn't work. Hopefully someone makes an update. Great work on this library, all the best.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested I was able to build the latest MariaDB4j from source with support for Apple Silicon (M1) processors.

Steps:

1. Clone the MariaDB4j GitHub repo and switch to the master branch.
2. Build MariaDB from source with ARM-64 support:
   `arch -arm64 brew install mariadb@10.2 --build-from-source`
3. Go to folder `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb@10.2/10.2.41` and copy all the required binaries from the `bin` and `script` subfolders to `MariaDB4j/DBs/mariaDB4j-db-mac64-10.2.11/src/main/resources/ch/vorburger/mariadb4j/mariadb-10.2.11/osx/bin`.
4. In a terminal go to `MariaDB4j/DBs/mariaDB4j-db-mac64-10.2.11` and do a `mvn install`. This will replace the maven dependency with the Mac x86 binaries with one that contains the ARM-64 binaries.

That's it, now your tests will run in your M1 :)

Note: if your project is not using the latest MariaDB4j version then first switch to the tag that matches your MariaDB4j dependency version.